# create email with send address already filled in on android

Tags: android, email, button, android-intent

I am making an app in android and I am trying to make it so that when you click a button, it opens up an email app of your choice (im using gmail) and automatically composes an email, how do I make it so that the send address is already filled in>

this is my code

```
public void send( View v ){
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(emailIntent);  
    }
```

Comment: Why are you passing in a parameter that you aren't even using...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need.

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "your_email_address");
```

Answer (score 0):

@user2109242

I will suggest you to use below code, because it will help you to **choose one of source like** : *email, gmail or skype* as well as **status of email** like: *Sent or Not*

```
public void sendFeedbackMessage(String subject, String message) {

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"your@gmail.com"});  
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        i.setType("message/rfc822");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send email via :"));
            Toast.makeText(ReservationActivity.this, "Email Sent.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(ReservationActivity.this, "There are no email applications installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        }
```